# PHP CLI Redirect to Log Background Operation

Tags: php, bash

I'm getting my butt kicked by this.

I am trying to background execution of a PHP script.  Of course, I want the output sent to a log file.  I've done this many times in the past, yet I can't get it to work this time.

Command Line Operation without Backgrounding works perfectly:

```
/app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log
```

If I try to background the command, the script seems to fail immediately.  Instead of taking a while to process, it returns immediately, the backend systems that would receive triggers from this script see nothing and nothing is written to the log file:

```
/app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log  2>&1 &
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running it in a subshell like this

```
(/app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log  2>&1) &
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I get the same result:

$ (/app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log 2>&1)  &
[25] 3152
$ 
[25]+  Stopped (/app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log 2>&1)

Comment: Does it require any interaction?

Comment: Also, if you don't redirect the output while backgrounded what happens?

Comment: No interaction is required and ... I was going to say the script works just fine when it is backgrounded without the redirect to log.  However, that is not true.  It fails.  I guess that explains my problem with the redirect.  Now, I have to figure out why the script would fail in background.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: So, I "found" the problem.  This works : php /app/lca/scripts/create_ss7auto_order.php --process_limit 23 --ss7auto_order_number X --audits_id 53 --clli X --login XXXXXXXX --larg_cnarg cnarg --abbr X >> /tmp/create_order.log  2>&1 &  .  For some reason, the path in the script "#!/usr/local/php-5.3.2/bin/php" is ignored when backgrounded.  I don't understand why though.  thanks again Greg Reynolds for pointing me in the right direction.  I can't accept your answer as it is not the right answer, but I appreciate the help.